# Angular cli build.. customize importing Feature Modules

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-module

In my angular starter app, I separate every isolated feature into it's own module and import all the feature Modules in the `AppModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { BusinessAccountManagementModule } from './business-account-management/business-account-management.module';
import { InvestigationModule } from './investigation/investigation.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CoreModule, // this will provide CommonModule, RouterModule and  BrowserModule for us to use

    /* Feature Modules */
    BusinessAccountManagementModule,
    InvestigationModule,

    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }
}
```

what i need is to customize which feature modules i want to import when i build ..

for example if i want to build release which contain `BusinessAccountManagementModule` so i want to do something like:

> ng build --featureModule BusinessAccountManagementModule

farther more:

> ng build --featureModule BusinessAccountManagementModule InvestigationModule ...

is there any chance to do it?

Comment: There is no such flag for ng build. However you can use lazy loading for loading specific modules. Note that all modules will be included in the build, but will not be loaded unless you specify it on your router config.

Comment: hi @VinodBhavnani, i putted that flat just for explaining that i aim to reach that flexibility... thanks for your suggestion but i don't want all module to be included in the build (just include what i want).. i am wondering if i can do something like: `npm build --featureModule BusinessAccountManagementModule`  which do: `prepare wanted modules`  && `ng build` ...